# Use JMS to dial phone number thru SIP

Tags: jms, sip

Did anyone try to implement some kind Java service so client library can send JMS message to it and dial a regular phone number?
We have Mitel 3300 Mex hardware which should support SIP.
Ideally it can play some pre-recorded voice when the peer side picks up, or event better text to speech?
Sheng